# CLion (c++). Got "error 127" when tried to debug

Tags: c++, debugging, binary, gdb, clion

In clion (c++) on Debian Linux when I want to debug I get this message:

```
During startup program exited with code 127.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Googling didn't help me. How can I fix that in CLion? Debian Linux.(GDB 7.8)

I tried to set a way to gdb manually but it didn't help… still 127

Here is my log file

```
{code}
2016-04-29 08:35:41,237 [ 299130]   INFO -        #com.jetbrains.cidr.cpp - Building: /usr/share/clion-2016.1.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /root/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Program_full-95f08d2c/95f08d2c/Debug --target all -- -j 8 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,377 [ 299270]   INFO - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - Debugger started 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,428 [ 299321]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - </usr/share/clion-2016.1.1/bin/gdb/bin/gdb -interpreter=mi

2016-04-29 08:35:41,429 [ 299322]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <=thread-group-added,id="i1" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,429 [ 299322]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~"GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8\n" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,429 [ 299322]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~"Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,429 [ 299322]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <gnuorg/licenses/l>\nThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type \"show copying\"\nand \"show warranty\" for details.\n" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,429 [ 299322]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~"This GDB was configured as \"x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu\".\nType \"show configuration\" for configuration details." 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,429 [ 299322]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~"\nFor bug reporting instructions, please see:\n" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,430 [ 299323]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~"<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.\n" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,430 [ 299323]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~"Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:\n</software/gdb/documentation/>.\n" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,430 [ 299323]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~"For help, type \"help\".\n" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,430 [ 299323]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~"Type \"apropos word\" to search for commands related to \"word\".\n" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,430 [ 299323]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,430 [ 299323]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-gdb-set print elements 0 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,431 [ 299324]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^done 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,432 [ 299325]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,432 [ 299325]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-gdb-set print repeats 0 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,433 [ 299326]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^done 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,433 [ 299326]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,433 [ 299326]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/clion-2016.1.1/bin/gdb/share/gdb/stl_printers')
sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/share/clion-2016.1.1/bin/gdb/share/gdb/stl_printers/libstdcxx/v6')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
end 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,434 [ 299327]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <&"python\n" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,434 [ 299327]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~">" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,435 [ 299328]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~">" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,435 [ 299328]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~">" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,435 [ 299328]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~">" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,435 [ 299328]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <~">" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,456 [ 299349]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^done 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,457 [ 299350]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,457 [ 299350]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-enable-pretty-printing 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,458 [ 299351]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^done 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,458 [ 299351]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,458 [ 299351]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-file-exec-and-symbols "/root/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Program_full-95f08d2c/95f08d2c/Debug/Program_full" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,606 [ 299499]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^done 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,607 [ 299500]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,607 [ 299500]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-break-insert -f "/root/ClionProjects/Program_full/main.cpp:61" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,608 [ 299501]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^done,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x00000000004037ba",func="main()",file="/root/ClionProjects/Program_full/main.cpp",fullname="/root/ClionProjects/Program_full/main.cpp",line="61",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="/root/ClionProjects/Program_full/main.cpp:61"} 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,609 [ 299502]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,609 [ 299502]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-break-insert -f "/root/ClionProjects/Program_full/main.cpp:65" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,610 [ 299503]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^done,bkpt={number="2",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x00000000004037c2",func="main()",file="/root/ClionProjects/Program_full/main.cpp",fullname="/root/ClionProjects/Program_full/main.cpp",line="65",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="/root/ClionProjects/Program_full/main.cpp:65"} 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,611 [ 299504]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,613 [ 299506]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-inferior-tty-set /dev/pts/1 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,617 [ 299510]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^done 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,618 [ 299511]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,620 [ 299513]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-exec-arguments  1> "/dev/pts/2" 2> "/dev/pts/3" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,624 [ 299517]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^done 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,644 [ 299537]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,664 [ 299557]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-exec-run 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,666 [ 299559]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <=thread-group-started,id="i1",pid="5773" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,686 [ 299579]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <=thread-created,id="1",group-id="i1" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,707 [ 299600]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <=thread-exited,id="1",group-id="i1" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,727 [ 299620]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <=thread-group-exited,id="i1" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,748 [ 299641]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^error,msg="During startup program exited with code 127." 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,769 [ 299662]   WARN - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-exec-run 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,769 [ 299662]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,769 [ 299662]   WARN - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^error,msg="During startup program exited with code 127." 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,790 [ 299683]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger -  
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: During startup program exited with code 127.
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.ExecutionResult.get(ExecutionResult.java:51)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver.executeCommand(GDBDriver.java:2438)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver.executeCommand(GDBDriver.java:2432)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver.launch(GDBDriver.java:433)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess.doLaunchTarget(CidrDebugProcess.java:453)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$7.run(CidrDebugProcess.java:443)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$MyCommandProcessor.consume(CidrDebugProcess.java:719)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$MyCommandProcessor.consume(CidrDebugProcess.java:709)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2$1.run(QueueProcessor.java:110)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2.consume(QueueProcessor.java:107)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2.consume(QueueProcessor.java:104)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$3$1.run(QueueProcessor.java:215)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$3.run(QueueProcessor.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBCommandException: During startup program exited with code 127.
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver.b(GDBDriver.java:2111)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver.a(GDBDriver.java:2103)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver.sendRequestAndWait(GDBDriver.java:2024)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver.sendRequestAndWait(GDBDriver.java:2016)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver.doLaunch(GDBDriver.java:519)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver$7.run(GDBDriver.java:506)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver$39.run(GDBDriver.java:2466)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$RunnableConsumer.consume(QueueProcessor.java:298)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$RunnableConsumer.consume(QueueProcessor.java:295)
    ... 13 more
2016-04-29 08:35:41,794 [ 299687]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-interpreter-exec console "signal 6" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,795 [ 299688]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <&"The program is not being run.\n" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,796 [ 299689]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^error,msg="The program is not being run." 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,796 [ 299689]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <(gdb) 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,797 [ 299690]   WARN - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - >-interpreter-exec console "signal 6" 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,797 [ 299690]   WARN - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <^error,msg="The program is not being run." 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,806 [ 299699]   INFO - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - Debugger exited with code 0 
2016-04-29 08:35:41,806 [ 299699]  DEBUG - brains.cidr.execution.debugger - <[terminated] 
{code}
```

Comment: Which operating system? Does clion list gdb in `File -> Settings -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains`?

Comment: @sitic Debian Linux. Yes gdb exists in Toolchains (GDB 7.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is a solution:

shch root -s /bin/bash
(If it gives an error with authentication - (comment auth sufficient pam_rootok.so) line in /etc/pam.d/chsh and try again) and finally reboot! It helped me

Comment: You're right, the root cause of the issue was IO redirection arguments that are not well understood by *csh-family shells (`1> ... 2> ...`). This is no more the case as of CLion 2017.1 and 2016.3.3, now it works fine regardless the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
CLion didn't tell me some times that some shared libraries are missing.

I had to add Environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH  in to configuration i want to run.

Hope it helps

Comment: Actually, what should I put as a parameter in LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: You should use path where Your *.so files are (assume that You're using some shared libraries)

Comment: Didn't help. Still 127

Answer (score 0):

And another possible answer is the path to valgrind is wrong.

In Preferences > Build, Execute... > Valgrind. Double check the Valgrind executable actually points to the executable and not just the direction.

My default setting on OSX was to the direction which was causing the error.