# Ubuntu - Debugging in CLion exits with code 127

Tags: c++, c, debugging, ubuntu, clion

I am running CLion 2017.1.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I click the "Debug"
button, the C++ project builds and then the debugger stops and exits with the error:

"During startup program exited with code 127.

Process finished with exit code 0"

I searched for this issue in StackOverflow and other forums but could not find any answer to resolve my issue. Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: I don't know what CLion is, but it sounds like your program is just quitting. Are you able to edit your question to include the code you're running, if it's small enough? I suspect this has nothing to do with the debugger and everything to do with your code.

Comment: 'During startup' ...... static constructor bug?

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+F8 to go to breakpoints list. Turn on the checkbox "When any is thrown" and try your debugging session once again. It will probably stops where the exception occurs.

Comment: Also, what happens if you run your program in Clion not in debug mode, just "Run" button?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812907/clion-c-got-error-127-when-tried-to-debug. I use CLION for Mac and have seen this issue in the past and that question helped me figure it out.

Comment: Are you able to debug your executable with GDB from command-line, without CLion?

Comment: Hi all, thanks so much for replying :)
As @ZeldaZach pointed out, the issue was because my SHELL variable was pointing to the wrong path. I found that out when I faced another issue of not being able to install any python packages using pip. When I googled that error, I happened to find out this SHELL variable issue. I changed it to /bin/bash using the command chsh -s /bin/bash root

Also, some debug libraries went missing, which I was able to restore using Ubuntu's Software Updater. Now, I am able to debug :)

Thanks so much all :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was because my SHELL variable was pointing to the wrong path. I found that out when I faced another issue of not being able to install any python packages using pip. When I googled that error, I happened to find out this SHELL variable issue.

Execute `echo $SHELL` in a terminal and check if it is a valid shell that you are using. I use the bash shell and hence changed it to `/bin/bash` using the command `chsh -s /bin/bash root`

Also, some debug libraries went missing, which I was able to restore using Ubuntu's Software Updater. Now, I am able to debug :)